# Make sure a string passed as argument does not cause an overflow

Tags: c

I have to make sure that a string passed as argument does not cause an overflow. I'm doing this by using strncpy, but the ending '\0', allocating the right amount of memory and so on gives me some troubles...

My solution is this:

```
l = strlen(argv[optind]);
if(l<MAX_LENGTH) {
    msg = malloc((l+1) * sizeof(char));
    msg = strcpy(msg, argv[optind]);
} else {
    msg = malloc((MAX_LENGTH+1) * sizeof(char));
    msg = strncpy(msg, argv[optind], MAX_LENGTH);
    msg[MAX_LENGTH+1] = '\0';
}
```

It works, but I'm wondering if it is really correct and if there is a more compact solution?

Comment: I think it is correct to code the above way. But you could also pass directly the argv[optind] (thru arguments, or pointers) to your internal routine, and not bother about such a limitation.

Comment: You may like to consider the fact that your platform will most likely already put a limitation on the argument size, so perhaps you can just go with `l + 1` always.

Comment: @Basile and Kerrek: This is part of an assignment from university. The requirements state that one should limit the string to a reasonable size. I have a feeling that a nasty teaching assistent will check that.

Comment: `msg[MAX_LENGTH+1] = '\0';` is wrong as it's accessing the char immediately following the end of the allocated memory block. It must be `msg[MAX_LENGTH] = '\0';`.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks, I just discovered that one.

Comment: Please DONT UPDATE YOUR UP to correct errors. That would make the comments useless for future viewers.

Comment: @wildpasser: Ok, sorry for that!

Comment: I took the freedom to rollback your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is about the simplest you can get:

```
size_t l;
char* msg;
...
l = strlen(argv[optind]);
if (l > MAX_LENGTH) l = MAX_LENGTH;

msg = malloc(l + 1);
if (msg == NULL) /* handle the error as appropriate*/;

memcpy(msg, argv[optind], l);
msg[l] = '\0';
```

Comment: the GNU function strnlen (an extension that can however be easily reimplemented) is interesting and could avoid another potentially possible problem with the strlen (think about execX family functions)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably replace all this code with:

```
msg = strdup(argv[optind]);
```

From `strdup(3)`:

```
   The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which
   is a duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is
   obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).

   The strndup() function is similar, but only copies at most n
   characters.  If s is longer than n, only n characters are
   copied, and a terminating null byte ('\0') is added.
```

**Update**

```
CONFORMING TO
   strdup() conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.  strndup(),
   strdupa(), and strndupa() are GNU extensions.
```

Comment: This has the semantic difference that it does not put a bound on the resulting allocation.

Comment: @Oli: good catch. I'm so used to thinking with my POSIX blinders on. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = strlen(argv[optind]);
if ( l < MAX_LENGTH) {
    msg = malloc(l+1);
    if (msg) strcpy(msg, argv[optind]);
} else {
    msg = malloc(MAX_LENGTH+1);
    if (msg) {
#if 1
        memcpy(msg, argv[optind], MAX_LENGTH);
#else
        strncpy(msg, argv[optind], MAX_LENGTH);
#endif
        msg[MAX_LENGTH] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of this? I don't think it improves readability, nor is it more compact.

Comment: The difference is in the last line. The OP used MAX_LENGTH+1 as an index (which is wrong). Also, I check for malloc() returning NULL.

Comment: Please DONT UPDATE your post to hide your errors. That would make the reactions useless for future viewers.

Comment: @wildplasser errors must be fixed in order to give a better answer! though, leaving a track of the fact that there was an error currently fixed would be nice, I agree.

Comment: Errors are fixed in the answers, not in the question. If there were no errors in the question, answers would not be needed at all.